# Rails URI.open Import is Deleting Punctuation from .TXT Import

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails method that is trying to pull saved `chapter` texts from `.txt` files saved on AWS from a very large legacy codebase.

After MUCH experimentation I have found that the following code as a method in my `chapter.rb` model works:

```
def summon_text 
    require 'open-uri'
    if !self.text || self.text == ""

        puts "https://the-petulant-poetess.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/stories/#{self.story.author.id}/#{self.id}.txt"
        readtext = URI.open("https://the-petulant-poetess.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/stories/#{self.story.author.id}/#{self.id}.txt".encode('UTF-8','ISO-8859-1', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "?"), "r:UTF-8") { |f| f.read }
        if readtext
            self.update(text: readtext)
            self.save!
        else
            puts "ISSUE WITH https://the-petulant-poetess.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/stories/#{self.story.author.id}/#{self.id}.txt"
        end
    end
end
```

I then run this in the console with `Chapter.find_each(&:summon_text)`.  It works to import the text, but a lot of the punctuation (and I mean almost a majority for some chapters) is missing, incorrect, or otherwise incorrect.

Here is what I know:

- The TXT files are in html format in their current incarnation.
- I am saving them in a `binary` datatype, as I had errors with just a `text` field.
- When troubleshooting I had some ASCII translation error messages, so that could be something?

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

EDIT:  SAMPLE ISSUE

A comment requested an example of what's happening.  Here is what a few sample paragraphs should look like (as per the `.txt` document (you can see the full source [here](https://the-petulant-poetess.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/stories/3675/24552.txt)):

> Maybe if he hadn’t broken up with Pansy again, had a fight with the
> Minister of Finance, and been threatened with a transfer to the
> Department of Mysteries, he would have said, “No,” to the two witches.
> He hadn’t even bothered checking them out.
>
> “It’ll be a change of pace,” said Padma Singh nee Patil.
>
> “You were a wizard at it when you were in school,” said Hermione
> Weasley nee Granger, adding some levity.

...and here is what it renders as (except SO filters out a bunch of errant spaces), after being downloaded (you can see the whole thing [here](https://tpp-2023-baaf294df375.herokuapp.com/stories/24552/chapters/24552)):

> Maybe if he hadnt broken up with Pansy again, had a fight with the
> Minister of Finance, and been threatened with a transfer to the
> Department of Mysteries, he would have said, No, to the two witches.
> He hadnt even bothered checking them out.
>
> Itll be a change of pace, said Padma Singh nee Patil.
>
> You were a wizard at it when you were in school, said Hermione
> Weasley nee Granger, adding some levity.

Comment: It's likely the encoding is off.  Might help if you give an example of some text and show what is expected vs what you are seeing.

Comment: @dbugger I added a sample of the text that should render versus what is appearing...

Comment: You are losing "smart" quote characters, which are not represented in ISO-8859-1, and were likely created in some form of windows. You need to do some byte translating or character replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save content to file then read from it

```rb
require 'active_record'
require 'tempfile'
require 'net/http'

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite3', database: ':memory:')

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  connection.create_table table_name, force: true do |t|
    t.string :name
  end
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  connection.create_table table_name, force: true do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.references :author
  end

  belongs_to :author
end

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  connection.create_table table_name, force: true do |t|
    t.text :text
    t.references :story
  end

  belongs_to :story

  def summon_text
    url = URI("https://the-petulant-poetess.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/stories/#{story.author.id}/#{id}.txt")
    content = Net::HTTP.get(url)

    ::Tempfile.open('.txt') do |file|
      file.write(content)
      text = File.read(file.path)
      update!(text: text)
    end
  end
end

author = Author.create!(name: 'JK Rowling')
story = Story.create!(name: 'Harry Potter', author: author)
chapter = Chapter.create!(text: 'The Magic Stone ...', story: story)
chapter.summon_text
pp chapter.text # Disclaimer:  As always, the characters remain the property of JK Rowling....
```

You can save this file to `mybookshelf.rb` and then run it with

```bash
ruby mybookshelf.rb
```

Comment: I like this approach!  Unfortunately that specific code is giving me `/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:30:in 'assign_attributes': When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument, String passed. (ArgumentError)` console errors.

Comment: @Liz it looks like you use old ruby. Try to replace `update!(text:)` with `update!(text: text)` (I edited my answer)

Comment: Okay, that works, but I'm still getting an `<Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x92" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8>` error for certain unicode characters.  (`\n`, `\x92`, `\x93`, and `\x94` specifically).

Answer (score 1):

The [`encode` method](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/Encoding.html) in your code is actually *not* affecting the contents of the text file. It is being applied to the URL string, which means it is just transforming the string that represents the URL, not the file that URL points to.

Meaning: `.encode('UTF-8','ISO-8859-1', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "?")` is essentially saying "treat this URL string as if it were encoded in ISO-8859-1, and convert it to UTF-8, replacing any non-convertible characters with `?`".
But if your URL does not contain any non-ASCII characters (which most URLs do not), this operation is not doing anything useful.

However, the way you are reading the file from the URL -- `URI.open(..., "r:UTF-8")` -- does have an effect on the file content. That is where the encoding of the file content is being specified. If the encoding is not specified correctly here, it could lead to issues like missing or incorrect characters in the resulting string.

I would suggest trying different character encodings when opening the file. The files could be using a different encoding than UTF-8, so opening them as such could cause some characters to be misinterpreted or replaced. To open the file as ISO-8859-1 and then convert to UTF-8, you could do something like this:

```rb
readtext = URI.open("https://the-petulant-poetess.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/stories/#{self.story.author.id}/#{self.id}.txt", "r:ISO-8859-1") { |f| f.read.encode('UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "?") }
```

That would open the file as `ISO-8859-1`, then converts it to `UTF-8`, replacing any non-convertible characters with `?`.

You can also, as [described in this article](https://lingohub.com/blog/2012/07/ruby-ensure_encoding-to-ensure-your-encoding), try the [`Manfred/Ensure-encoding`](https://github.com/Manfred/Ensure-encoding) gem, to ascertain the preferred encoding in Strings coming from untrusted sources.

---

> the suggested line you mentioned above gave me a `'open_http': 403 Forbidden (OpenURI::HTTPError)` error.

Given that you are using AWS S3 to host your files, are you sure the correct permissions are set for the files you are trying to access? Check the [bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html) or the [IAM policy related to your S3 resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-walkthroughs-managing-access.html).

If permissions are not an issue, an alternate method to use when working with AWS S3 is to use the [AWS SDK for Ruby](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/) ([`aws-sdk-s3` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk-s3)). That gives you the ability to manage your S3 buckets and objects directly and may bypass any issues you are experiencing with `open-uri`.

```rb
def summon_text
  require 'aws-sdk-s3'
  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-east-2')

  # assuming story.author.id and id are already defined
  object = s3.bucket('the-petulant-poetess').object("stories/#{self.story.author.id}/#{self.id}.txt")

  if object.exists?
    readtext = object.get.body.read.encode('UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "?")
    if readtext
      self.update(text: readtext)
      self.save!
    else
      puts "ISSUE WITH https://the-petulant-poetess.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/stories/#{self.story.author.id}/#{self.id}.txt"
    end
  end
end
```

That is a direct read from S3, which should respect whatever encoding the file has, then forces an encode to UTF-8.
You will need to set your AWS credentials (i.e., your Access Key ID and Secret Access Key) in your environment for the AWS SDK to work correctly.

Comment: So great to know that my `.encode` was applying to the statement not the file!

Unfortunately, the suggested line you mentioned above gave me a `'open_http': 403 Forbidden (OpenURI::HTTPError)` error.